# Apache2 with web.py and php - php services not working

Tags: php, python, apache, mod-wsgi

I have deployed my web.py application using apache2 and the configuration looks as follows.

```
<VirtualHost _default_ *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@project.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ErrorLog /var/www/Engine/log/error.log
CustomLog /var/www/Engine/log/access.log combined

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/Engine/Engine.py
Alias /static /var/www/html
AddType text/html .py
WSGIDaemonProcess www-data threads=15
WSGIProcessGroup www-data

WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

</VirtualHost>

<Directory /var/www/html>
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

**Problem:**

I have some php services hosted inside /var/www/html/apis . Those used to work before configuring with mod_wsgi, but when i request now, it says 404 error.

**Question:**
How to configure both Python and php services work together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding:

```
Alias /apis/ /var/www/html/apis/
```

Also see:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/09/hosting-php-web-applications-in.html